# Arduino Nano 33 IoT LSM6DS3: get gyro angle in degrees

Tags: arduino-nano, accelerometer, gyroscope, imu

I have an Arduino Nano 33 IoT and I want to get the angle of it using the built-in gyro but I can't seem to find any example code that does this.

The default gyro and accelerometer example code doesn't help. Is it even possible to do this?

Comment: a gyro detects the rate of angular change, not an absolute angle ... an accelerometer can measure an angle with respect to gravity

Comment: I tried looking for both but there is no code that does it. Could you help me find it?

Comment: All I can find is changing numbers but no angles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wil have to calculate the angles. Some trigonometry is required, and for the gyroscopes, also some integration. You can read about it [here](http://www.starlino.com/imu_guide.html), and in many other places.

You will get the best results if you combine the data from the gyroscopes and the accelerometers using a *complementary filter*, a *Kalman filter*, or an other algorithm. These are also easily googled.

There is some example code for the LSM6DS3 IMU on the Nano 33 IoT [here](https://github.com/owennewo/Arduino_LSM6DS3/blob/master/examples/RollPitchYaw/RollPitchYaw.ino) on Github.

Comment: This is the best solution. This filter is a lot faster than the MadgwickAHRS! Amazing!

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to use a filter library on top of the output of the gyro as well as the accelerometer data (both is used!) to get angles ... https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/madgwick

Here is a working example that prints the pitch of the sensor from +90 to -90 degrees:

```
//#include <SPI.h>
//#include <Wire.h>  
#include <Arduino_LSM6DS3.h>
#include <MadgwickAHRS.h>
#include <Math.h>

float pitchFilteredOld;
Madgwick filter;
const float sensorRate = 104.00;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  if(!IMU.begin())  {
    Serial.println("Failed to initialize IMU!");
    while (1);
  }
  filter.begin(sensorRate);
  Serial.println("Setup complete!");
}  
void loop() {
  float xAcc, yAcc, zAcc;
  float xGyro, yGyro, zGyro;
  float roll, pitch, heading;
  if(IMU.accelerationAvailable() && IMU.gyroscopeAvailable()){
    IMU.readAcceleration(xAcc, yAcc, zAcc);
    IMU.readGyroscope(xGyro, yGyro, zGyro); 
    filter.updateIMU(xGyro, yGyro, zGyro, xAcc, yAcc, zAcc);
    pitch = filter.getPitch();
    float pitchFiltered = 0.1 * pitch + 0.9 * pitchFilteredOld; // low pass filter
    Serial.println("pitch: " + String(pitchFiltered));
    pitchFilteredOld = pitchFiltered;
  }
}
```